# Ungit stopped working after updating

Tags: node.js, npm, ungit

After updating Ungit stopped working. Please tell me what is the problem? When I run ungit an error:

> module.js:327
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'npm'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\ashev_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ungit\src\sysinfo.js:10:11)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. However, I installed ungit for the very for time and experienced the same error.

It seems that this issue is specific to  v0.10.2

In my case I just wanted to see a working version of ungit. I did not need a specific feature of the latest  version, so I uninstalled the fresh install and reverted  to the prior version.

npm uninstall -g   ungit

npm install –g ungit@"v0.10.1"

There’s a ticket on github for this issue
"Launching error after fresh install #766"

https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit/issues/766